# Android Studio compiler error: cannot find a method listed in android studio tutorial

Tags: java, android

I am new to android studio and I am reading the tutorials on i-programmer located here (http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/android/5914-android-adventures-activity-and-ui.html?start=2)

The two objects in the environment are a button and a large text widget instanced
in android studio's xml designer.

The problem:  A method for setting text referenced in the tutorial is showing this error message when I try to run the code:   error: cannot find symbol method setText(String)

And this error shows up in the text editor: Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.String)'

Provided Source Code:

```
package com.example.helloworld1.helloworld1;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void onButtonClick(View v){
    Button button=(Button) v;
    v.setText("I've Been Clicked!");  //  This is where the error happens
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to use `button` instead of `v`.

```
button.setText("I've Been Clicked!");
```

Comment: This has resolved my problem.  I appreciate your fast response to my question.